# If Where in stored procedure

Tags: sql

i have a stored procedure in which I have a variable which can be null or set for an ID.
I want to have a where clause only if the variable is not null.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @managerID int;
SET @managerID = null;
SET @managerID = 6 //This value will come by parameter through stored procude
Select * from Provision 
where manager = @managerID //This should only be here, when the managerID is not null
```

Comment: dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
where manager = @managerID or @ManagerId is null
```

However, if you are doing this from an application, you might want to construct the `where` clause based on the conditions.  Database optimizers have a hard time with `or` in the `from` clause, so it is better to just have a list of conditions connect by `and`.

Answer (score 0):

`@managerID` will return true if it is null and it will return all rows

```
DECLARE @managerID int;
SET @managerID = null;
SET @managerID = 6 
Select * from Provision 
where manager = @managerID OR @managerID is null
```